# Python: Image Segmentation as pre-process for Classification

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

What technique do you recommend to **segment** the characters in this image to be ready to fed a model like the ones use with MNIST dataset; because they take one character at a time. This question is regadless the importance of transforming the image and the binarization of it.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point i would try the following:

1. Use OTSU threshold.
2. Than do some morphological operations to get rid of noise and to isolate each digit.
3. Run connected component labling.
4. Fed each connected component to your classifier to get recognize the digit if the classification score is low discard.
5. Final validation you expect all the digit to be more or less on line and in more or less some constant distance from each other.

Here are the first 4 stages. Now you need to add your recognition software to recognize the digits.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Params
EPSSILON = 0.4
MIN_AREA = 10
BIG_AREA = 75

# Read img
img = cv2.imread('i.jpg',0)

# Otzu threshold
a,thI =  cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Morpholgical
se = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(1,1))
thIMor = cv2.morphologyEx(thI,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,se)

# Connected compoent labling
stats = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thIMor,connectivity=8)

num_labels = stats[0]
labels = stats[1]
labelStats = stats[2]

# We expect the conneccted compoennt of the numbers to be more or less with a constats ratio
# So we find the medina ratio of all the comeonets because the majorty of connected compoent are numbers
ratios = []
for label in range(num_labels):

    connectedCompoentWidth = labelStats[label,cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
    connectedCompoentHeight = labelStats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]

    ratios.append(float(connectedCompoentWidth)/float(connectedCompoentHeight))

# Find median ratio
medianRatio = np.median(np.asarray(ratios))

# Go over all the connected component again and filter out compoennt that are far from the ratio
filterdI = np.zeros_like(thIMor)
filterdI[labels!=0] = 255
for label in range(num_labels):

    # Ignore biggest label
    if(label==1):
        filterdI[labels == label] = 0
        continue

    connectedCompoentWidth = labelStats[label,cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
    connectedCompoentHeight = labelStats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]

    ratio = float(connectedCompoentWidth)/float(connectedCompoentHeight)
    if ratio > medianRatio + EPSSILON or ratio < medianRatio - EPSSILON:
        filterdI[labels==label] = 0

    # Filter small or large compoennt
    if labelStats[label,cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] < MIN_AREA or labelStats[label,cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] > BIG_AREA:
        filterdI[labels == label] = 0

plt.imshow(filterdI)


# Now go over each of the left compoenet and run the number recognotion
stats = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(filterdI,connectivity=8)
num_labels = stats[0]
labels = stats[1]
labelStats = stats[2]

for label in range(num_labels):

    # Crop the bounding box around the component
    left = labelStats[label,cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
    top = labelStats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]
    width = labelStats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
    height = labelStats[label, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
    candidateDigit = labels[top:top+height,left:left+width]


    # plt.figure(label)
    # plt.imshow(candidateDigit)
```

[image: OTSU thrshold image]

Comment: Any idea on 2 and 3? A little bit more of information, please?

Comment: for 2 look at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html

Comment: for 3 look at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

Comment: Thank you @Amiraty do you mind showing me some code for 3?

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look

Comment: Amazing! Question. If you have a blank template, would not be better to use it to remove the lines (horizontal and vertical)?

Comment: Yes if you know that the orientation of the document is the same as the template. In the example you gave the document is tilted. You can still use it if you unrotate the document before you use the template.

Answer (score 0):

I connect to the Amitay answer.

For the 2:
I would use thinning as morphological operation (look [thinning algorithm in opencv](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322113207/http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/))

For the 3:
And in OpenCV 3.0 there is already a function called [cv::connectedComponents](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a))

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks. do you have the same documentation in python?

Comment: As regards OpenCV, usually the funtions have exactly the same arguments as the C++ ones, so cv2.connectedComponents should do the job.

Comment: As regards the thinning algorithm I do not have a reference to a Python code, but if you read it is very easy to transpose in python, I'm sure you will have no difficulties, it is just again about using the counterpart opencv functions in python.

Comment: Nothing to add for now, happy coding :)